# How to read a number above 999 that is separated by a comma (eg. 10,000)?

Tags: c

I'm new to C (and programming) and it's possible that my question can be answered with some basic searching and reading; please point me to an answer to the question if it exists.

Let's say that I want to read a number that can possibly be above 999 from the user. From my experience, if I enter the value 10,000 (including the comma), the program would read the number until the comma and then stop taking input. Thus, the input would be 10 instead of 10000.

**How can I make it read '10,000' as if it is 10000?**

Comment: Read as a string, remove all commas from the string, parse string to convert it to an integer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. That's my initial thought as well. I probably need to read on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void RemoveChar(char* Number, char chartoberemoved)
{
    char *p, *s;
    p = s = Number;
    while (*s)//Run until last \r\n
    {

        if (*s != chartoberemoved)
        {
            *p++ = *s;
        }
        /* We always advance s. */
        s++;

    }
    /* We 0-terminate p. */
    *p = 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char array[32];
    if (!argv[1])
        return -1;
    strcpy(array, argv[1]);
    RemoveChar(array, ',');
    int num = atoi(array);
    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most implementation of scanf and printf on Linux support `'` to tell that the number may have a thousands separator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, ""); // set the locale so that "," is a thousands separator

    const char* string = "10,000";

    float num = 0;
    sscanf(string, "%'f", &num);
    printf("%f\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

returns

```
10000.000000
```

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-printf/

Answer (score -1):

use `strtok` its information and documentation can be found here. [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)